Why does $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L \implies f = \Theta(g)$ not hold when $L=0$?
I am currently seeing a contradiction from my use of the "theorem"

For any $2$ functions $f : \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $g: \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$, if $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$ where $L \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f = \Theta(g)$

when $L=0$, although I seem to have proved this theorem. (Incidentally, other sources in which I have seen this theorem, like here, exclude $L=0$). So I wanted to present both my proof of this statement, and the contradiction I found deriving from it, and ask where I have committed an error. The contradiction I have deriving from this statement is that $x = \Theta(x^2)$, which is certainly false; $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac x {x^2} = \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac 1 x = 0$, so the above statement allows us to conclude that $x = \Theta(x^2)$. And here is my proof of the above theorem:
$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = L \iff \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\exists \delta \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} x>\delta \implies |\frac {f(x)}{g(x)} - L| < \epsilon$, so $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\exists \delta \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} x>\delta \implies -\epsilon<\frac {f(x)}{g(x)} - L < \epsilon$, whence $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \exists \delta \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} x>\delta \implies (L-\epsilon)\cdot g(x)<f(x) < (L+\epsilon) \cdot g(x)$, Q.E.D..
I don't see anything in the above line of reasoning which prevents the argument from proceeding when $L=0$. So where is my mistake?
For context, the definition of theta I am using only is defined for functions $f : \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $g : \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$, and it is that $f = \Theta(g)$ if and only if $f=O(g)$ and $f = \Omega(g)$, where $f=O(g) \iff \exists c \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}f(x) \le c \cdot g(x)$, and $f = \Omega(g) \iff g = O(f)$. Also, I figured out that it is equivalent for $f$ to be upper bounded for $g$ times a constant on all values of its domain, and to be upper bounded by $g$ times some constant for all values of its domain bigger than a certain point (given that the domain is the positive integers, as it is here), which I used in my proof.

So what would be some $c>0$ such that, for all $x$, $g(x)\le cf(x)$ ?

@SassatelliGiulo doesn't  $c= L- \epsilon$ where $\epsilon = -L + 1$ work? (I changed my proof to quantify epsilon over all reals instead of only positive reals to allow for this choice). My proof shows this holds only for all $x$ greater than delta, but I showed that if there is some $c>0$ for all $x$ greater than delta, then there then there exists another constant $k$ such that $g(x) \le kf(x)$ for all $x$

The usual strategy for debugging an argument when a counterexample exists is to "plug the counterexample into the argument" and look for false statements and invalid deductions. <> Here, the counterexample appears to be $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$, and I read @SassatelliGiulio's (+1) comment as meaning "what is some $c > 0$ such that $x^2 \leq cx$ for all $x > 0$?" <> Since $L = 0$, $c = L - \epsilon$ is not positive. <> That just means the proposed choice "doesn't work," but presumably it's clear there exists no such $c$...?

@PrincessMia But here $L-(-L+1)=2L-1=-1<0$.

You are claiming that
$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \exists \delta \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} x>\delta \implies (L-\epsilon)\cdot g(x)<f(x) < (L+\epsilon) \cdot g(x)$
Implies both $g = O(f)$ and $f = O(g)$. The latter is always true but the former is not when $L = 0$, because we have $-\epsilon g(x) < f(x)$ or equivalently $g(x) > -\epsilon^{-1} f(x)$, for all $\epsilon$. If $L \neq 0$, we can choose $\epsilon = \frac L2$ to have $\frac L2 g(x) < f(x)$ thus $g(x) < \frac2L f(x)$, which does yield $g = O(f)$.

Your proof is partial. It only gets you to the fact that $f = O(g)$ because essentially it means you can bound $f$ by $g$. For proving $f = \Theta(g)$, you'll need to get something like $g \leq c \cdot f$ so you'd need your $L$ in the denominator which of course isn't possible if $L = 0$.
Although once you add the condition $L \neq 0$ your proposition holds.

Limit
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = L $$
of course implies $f=O(g)$, in both cases $L=0$ and $L>0$. But for $\Theta$ we also need $g=O(f)$, which for $L=0$ we, generally, have not as gives example $g(n)=n^2$ and $f(n)=n$: we have $n^2\notin O(n)$. BTW, try formally proof last.
